# How do I iterate through a csv file in python to edit the URLs stored and open them?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

New to python, but have about 3+ years of amateur experience in C.

I have a .csv file in Excel with about 30 URLs in a column in the following format:

b'https://www.facebook.com/ESPN/posts/1914426995270714'

How do I iterate through the column with these URLs in the Excel file and edit the strings to turn them into links like this:

'https://www.facebook.com/ESPN/posts/1914426995270714'

Also, what module could I use to open the links and write their contents (the text) to a new column? I know there are plenty of modules to grab the article contents but I don't know how to actually write that into the csv after.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Removing the leading b, you can do using search and replace with a simple editor or did you specifically want it to be a python exercise?

Comment: I wanted to do it with Python for the sake of learning

Answer (score 2):

check the 'csv' module.
use this code to read the data

```
import csv
with open('yourfileName.csv', mode='r') as infile:
     reader = csv.reader(infile)
     for rows in reader:
          data = rows[2:-1] #to remove the b' and ' characters
```

then you will most probably need a simple web **scraper** to read the data from each link, check "thenewboston" web crawler playlist on youtube, you can start from there.